# WooCommerce API orders parameters not working

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

i'm using [woo commerce api documentation](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders)

and i'm using this code

```
$woocommerce = new Client($woocommerce_website_url, $woocommerce_customer_key, $woocommerce_consumer_secret, array(
  'wp_api' => true,
  'version' => 'wc/v3',
  'query_string_auth' => true 
));
$woocommerce->get('orders',["created_at_min"=>$date]);
```

But i'm getting all the orders but i want filter of **created_at_min** of orders and it's not working. I'm at this point from last many hours and don't know what to do. any kind of help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution and this code worked for me:-

```
$woocommerce->get('orders', array( 'after' => $date) );
```